# Getting state code and country code from area code of phone number

Tags: salesforce-communities

I need to extract the state code and the country code from incoming web-to-lead phone number in Salesforce

Example if the area code of a phone number is (421)
I need a way to populate the state code and the country code with the appropriate data

Answer (score 0):

there is a way for this but it needs backend coding for this in which whenever a lead is generated from the web it checks the area code from the phone number and decides what will be the appropriate state code and country code for the given area code.

And with the help of backend coding, we can set the add and remove the area codes dynamically.

But right now salesforce doesn't have any automated based feature for this requirement.